# sklearn failing to import in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wrote a little python program which uses the kmeans algorithm to cluster data from an excel file. I am using the PyCharm IDE to write this code. I had gone through the debugging process and was happy with my work when I encountered a problem:

I opened the cmd (I'm on Windows) and typed in the following:

```
cd C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\clusterAnalysis
python kMeansClustering.py
```

But to my surprise this mess got thrown back at me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kMeansClustering.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils'
```

I assume it's because I must have installed sklearn to the wrong place with pip. Nervously, I just ignored this and used pyinstaller to make a .exe, and, to no surprise, the .exe failed for the exact same reason. Any tips?

Here's a picture of the project file if it helps:
[PyCharm Project File Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBIWq.png)

Comment: `scikit-learn` install is broken. Update it: `pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`

Comment: @Marat `Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade`

Comment: try adding `--force-reinstall` to pip parameters then

Comment: @Marat I think I am using pip in the wrong directory.  `WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.` Should I have executed `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall scikit-learn` in a different directory?

Comment: Python packages sometimes install commands that meant to be accessible from console. This message says that these commands will not be accessible until you include their location in the `PATH`. It does not affect Python imports

Comment: Try ```pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall scikit-learn``` with administrator access

Comment: First try adding ```c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Scripts\``` to path

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me .First **uninstall** sklearn

```
       pip uninstall sklearn
```

Then **reinstall** the sklearn

```
       pip install sklearn
```

Comment: Ok now I can't even install sklearn... `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\sklearn\\datasets\\tests\\data\\openml\\292\\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz'`
I think I am going to just delete everything python related on my computer and start fresh.

Comment: I think  you should  fix your problem without  clearing  python if you do so your local  environment it will get loss  if you dont  work on environment  you can clear you python